# Numpy/Python Scalability

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, scipy, scientific-computing

I use Python and Numpy mainly for scientific programming. A typical task is to construct and then diagonalize many medium-sized matrices. I try to avoid any for loops and mainly use advanced numpy features like np.einsum to save resources. For diagonalization I pass a (#matrices, n, n) array to numpy.linalg.eigh().
Avoiding the slow python stuff, I usually get very good results that are reasonably fast, which is to be expected since numpy uses BLAS/LAPACK.

However, I made the experience that this scales very poorly. As soon as I come close to what I can load onto the RAM of my laptop, the code takes much longer than what one would expect from the increased computational effort. E.g.: Diagonalizing 2601 (on a 51x51 grid) 84x84 complex matrices takes more than 20 times as long as doing the same thing 441 times  (on a 21x21 grid).

I now that there's always a peformance-memory tradeoff, but I don't understand why this scales so badly.

BTW: I am looking for a solution within python. I don't want to switch to C++ or Fortran. But I would be open to use numba or cython (if it works in my IDE and help with the problem).

Here's some pseudo code to specify the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eigh

def construct_M(x, y, params):
do something
return M

np = 51
a = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, np)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(a, a, indexing='ij')
construct_M(xx, yy)
M.shape
>>> (2601, 84, 84)

# that's the time consuming part
E, v = eigh(M)
```

Comment: We can not judge the time complexity and "scalability" of your code without the code.

Comment: I would test the scaling of the first (batch) dimension separately from the last 2 (the square matrix).  I suspect `eigh` iterates on the first, passing 2d arrays to a library function.

Comment: I found that passing it like this is much faster than going over the first axis in a loop and calling eigh. However, and this is basically the essence of my question, only as long as the matrices that are past don't become large enough to fill up my laptop's RAM.